# Blocking directed paths on a DAG with a linear number of vertex defects

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed acyclic graph.
Define the set of all directed paths in $G$ by $\Gamma$.
Given a subset $W\subseteq V$, let
$\Gamma_W\subseteq \Gamma$ be the set of all paths in $\Gamma$ supported on $V\backslash W$.
Now define $l(W)$ to be:
$$l(W)=max_{\gamma\in \Gamma_W} |\gamma|$$

I want to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ and every $k>0$, there exists a constant $L$ such that  for any directed acyclic graph $G=(V, E)$ with ingoing and outgoing degree bounded by $k$, there exists a subset $W\subseteq V$ such that $\frac{|W|}{|V|}<\epsilon$  and $l(W)<L$.

While it is obviously true for directed trees since you can just remove all vertices at some given depths to block any path going down the tree, the same approach fails to work in more general DAGs.
Moreover, the statement fails to be true if we remove the constant degree requirement for $G$.

Any direction or idea would be welcome.

PS. [Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897003/blocking-directed-paths-on-a-dag-with-a-linear-number-of-vertex-defects) at MSE.

Comment: What do you mean by "supported on" $V \setminus W$? Do you mean that a path $\gamma \in \Gamma_W$ has all vertices in $V \setminus W$ or some vertices. And by $|\gamma|$ you mean the number of vertices in the path $\gamma$?

Comment: All vertices in $V\backslash W$. And yes, $|\gamma|$  is the number of vertices in $\gamma$

Comment: @Forester Erm.. Is there anything wrong with my counterexample in the MSE thread that prompted you to revive this MO thread with a bounty?

Comment: @fedga Sir, the bounty is from 6 days ago. Your answer was wonderful.

Comment: @Forester Indeed. I misread the time stamp. My apologies then :-)